# I'm very confused about this in Lax's book. Why does infinite decimal representation not produce infinite 9?

Tags: real-analysis

1.2 Numbers and the Least Upper Bound Theorem

1.2a Numbers as Infinite Decimals

There are two familiar ways of looking at numbers: as infinite decimals
and as points on a number line. The integers divide the number line into
infinitely many intervals of unit length. If we include the left
endpoint of each interval but not the right, we can cover the number
line with nonoverlapping intervals such that each number a belongs to
exactly one of them,$$\(\ n\  \leq \ a\  < \ n + 1\)$$. Each interval can be
subdivided into ten subintervals of length $$\(\frac{1}{10}\)$$. As before,
if we agree to count the left endpoint but not the right as part of each
interval, the intervals do not overlap. Our number a belongs to exactly
one of these ten subintervals, say to

$$\(n + \frac{\alpha_{1}}{10} \leq a < n + \frac{\alpha_{1} + 1}{10}\ \).$$

Thus using the representation of $\(a\)$ as a point on the number line and
the procedure just described, we can find $\(\alpha_{k}\)$ in
$\(a\  = \ n.\alpha 1\alpha 2\ ...\alpha_{k}\ ...\ \)$by determining the
appropriate interval in the $\(k\)$th step of this process. Conversely,
once we have the decimal representation of a number, we can identify its
location on the number line.

Repeated Nines in Decimals.
The method we described for representing numbers as infinite decimals does not result in decimal fractions that end with infinitely many nines. Nevertheless, such
decimals come up when we do arithmetic with infinite decimals. For instance, take the sum

$
\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3} =1 \\
$

$
\frac{1}{3} = 0.3333333\ldots and 
\frac{2}{3} = 0.6666666\ldots \\
$

$
so \ 1 = 0.9999999\ldots \\
$

question：I know that 1 is 0.999999..., which are two identical numbers. But I can't understand why we can't get infinite 9 using the method of dividing the interval into 10 parts as described by Lax?

Comment: "*if we agree to count the left endpoint* **but not the right** *as part of each interval,...*"

Comment: @JMoravitz What does it mean?

Comment: It means that if taking the interval $[0,1)$ and dividing into the ten intervals $[0,0.1),[0.1,0.2),[0.2,0.3),\dots[0.9,1)$ you find that $0.999\dots$ is not in any of those intervals since it is the rightmost endpoint of the last interval in that list... but of course if you were to divide $[0,2)$ into twenty intervals $[0,0.1),[0.1,0.2),\dots,[1.9,2)$ that $0.999\dots$ does lie within the interval $[1,1.1)$

Comment: My confusion is, if it can express an infinite number of 3s, why can't it express an infinite number of 9s? Is it just because 0.9999 of infinite 9s is replaced by 1?

Comment: If we have buckets of various colors... red, green, blue,... and we have a collection of balls of various colors... red, green, blue... and when we take a ball we decide to put it in the matching bucket... if we pick up a red ball we want to put it in the red bucket.  Here, rather than balls and buckets, we are talking about numbers and intervals... We pick up the number $\frac{1}{3}$ and we want to put it into a bucket... we put it into the bucket $[0.3,0.4)$.  If we were to pick up the number $0.9999\dots$ the "bucket" we would want to put it in is $[1,1.1)$... **not** $[0.9,1)$

Comment: As far as I know from the book, does this mean that $a$ is $0.99999...$, it cannot be found larger than a in $[0.9,1)$ so $a<1$, it cannot be found smaller than a in $[1,1.1)$ Therefore $a>1$. Due to Trichotomy, $a=1$?, but $0.33333...$ can be thrown into $[0.3, 0.4)$, so $0.33333...$ is unique?

Comment: thank you ，I am reason with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine what has to happen in order for the decimal expansion of a number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ to end with infinitely many nines. This means that starting with some interval $I = [a, b)$, we have the following:

- $x$ belongs to $I$.
- When $I$ is divided into $10$ subintervals of equal lengths, $x$ belongs to the rightmost of them; name this smaller interval $I_1$.
- When $I_1$ is further divided into $10$ subintervals of equal lengths, $x$ again belongs to the rightmost of them; name it $I_2$.
- The pattern continues.

Effectively, $x$ belongs to the intersection of all $I_n$'s. If we write $a = b - d$ for some $d > 0$, we can see that

$$\begin{align*} I & = [b - d, b) \\[1ex]
I_1 & = \left[ b - \frac{d}{10}, b \right) \\[1ex]
I_2 & = \left[ b - \frac{d}{100}, b \right) \\[1ex]
& \vdots \end{align*}$$

Thus $x \in \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ b - \frac{d}{10^n}, b \right)$. But this intersection is empty, so $x$ can not be there - hence it was impossible for the decimal expansion of $x$ to end with infinitely many nines.

On the other hand, the intersection

$$[a, a+d) \cap \left[ a + \frac{3}{10}d, a + \frac{4}{10}d \right) \cap \left[ a + \frac{33}{100}d , a + \frac{34}{100}d \right) \ldots$$

in non-empty, which is why an expansion like $0.333\ldots$ is possible.

As for the number $x = 1$, both $x = 1.000\ldots$ and $x = 0.999\ldots$ are correct decimal expansions of $x$. But the procedure described by Lax would simply result in the first expansion and not in the second.

Comment: I think adding explanations of why the first intersection is empty ($10^n$ is arbitrarily large for $n$ large) and the second one is not (contains $a + d/3$) would be helpful.

Comment: got it ， thank you 